# Use of partitioners in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, transformation, rdd, partitioning, shuffle

Hy, I have a question about partitioning in Spark,in *Learning Spark* book, authors said that partitioning can be useful, like for example during **PageRank** at page 66 and they write :

> since links is a static dataset, we partition it at the start with
>   partitionBy(), so that it does not need to be shuffled across the
>   network

Now I'm focused about this example, but my questions are general:

1. **why a partitioned RDD doesn't need to be shuffled?**
2. **PartitionBy() is a wide transformation,so it will produce shuffle anyway,right?**
3. **Could someone illustrate a concrete example and what happen into each  single node when partitionBy happens?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why a partitioned RDD doesn't need to be shuffled?

When the author does:

```
val links = sc.objectFile[(String, Seq[String])]("links")
 .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(100))
 .persist()
```

He's partitioning the data set into 100 partitions where each key will be hashed to a given partition (`pageId` in the given example). This means that the same key will be stored in a *single given partition*. Then, when he does the `join`:

```
val contributions = links.join(ranks)
```

All chunks of data with the same `pageId` should already be located on the same executor, avoiding the need for a shuffle between different nodes in the cluster.

> PartitionBy() is a wide transformation,so it will produce shuffle
>   anyway, right?

Yes, `partitionBy` produces a `ShuffleRDD[K, V, V]`:

```
def partitionBy(partitioner: Partitioner): RDD[(K, V)] = self.withScope {
  if (keyClass.isArray && partitioner.isInstanceOf[HashPartitioner]) {
    throw new SparkException("HashPartitioner cannot partition array keys.")
  }
  if (self.partitioner == Some(partitioner)) {
    self
  } else {
    new ShuffledRDD[K, V, V](self, partitioner)
  }
}
```

> Could someone illustrate a concrete example and what happen into each
>   single node when partitionBy happens?

Basically, `partitionBy` will do the following:

[image: Hash Partitioning]

It will hash the key modulu the number of partitions (100 in this case), and since it relys on the fact that the same key will always produce the same hashcode, it will package all data from a given id (in our case, `pageId`) to the same partition, such that when you `join`, all data will be available in that partition already, avoiding the need for a shuffle.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer @Yuval.

Comment: But if for avoid shuffle during join, we need to do shuffle at the beginning, what's the advantage? Maybe just when the partitioned RDD is used many times? Or what?

Comment: @Giorgio If we hadn't prematurely partitioned the RDD and persisted it, then each iteration on it would incur a shuffle. The way that we shuffle once and reuse many times save us the overhead in the next few iterations.

Comment: I have one more question about it, you sad that after partitioning RDD, all chunks of data will be already available in the executors for next iterations, but when Spark should will do join, this result in a shuffle for just ranks RDD? I mean,  when shuffle happens, all chunks of data of ranks RDD will be fetch from the executors where reside links data?  Spark will do some optimization when see that links RDD is partitioned? And will shuffle data just for the not partitioned RDD?

Comment: @Giorgio Since ranks data is created from the `links` RDD, all keys (`pageId`) it contains should already be available locally in the partitions being processed by each task.

Comment: Yes, right!! I missed it, but more in general? If you will join two not related RDD? Suppose ranks is not created from links? What will happens?

Comment: @Giorgio Generally, `join` is a wide transformation. If two non hash partitioned RDDs are joined, data will need to be moved around between executors, causing a shuffle of data around.

Comment: But if the two RDD are not related, and  if one of them is partitioned and the other no? Join will cause just shuffle for not partitioned RDD? Thanks